# Is it possible to run pdfgrep with keywords stored in a array?

Tags: bash, shell

I want search in PDF files some different words; using pdfgrep https://pdfgrep.org/doc.html I can do it, but I'm not able to run many times, one for each word present in the array.

Then I want save every output in a different single file.

```
#!/bin/bash

function search_elements(){
   array=("$@")
   for i in "${array[@]}";
       do
              pdfgrep -Hir ' "$i" ' . 
       done
}

array = ("gomma" "lacca" "bromo")

search_elements "$(array[@])"
```

This is the output from ShellCheck:

- Line 5: [SC2034](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2034)

  ```
  for i in "${array[@]}";
  ^-- SC2034 (warning): i appears unused. Verify use (or export if used externally).
  ```
- Line 7: [SC2016](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2016)

  ```
              pdfgrep -Hir ' "$i" ' .
                           ^-- SC2016 (info): Expressions don't expand in single quotes, use double quotes for that.
  ```
- Line 11: [SC2283](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2283) [SC1036](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC1036) [SC1088](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC1088)

  ```
  array = ("gomma" "lacca" "bromo")
        ^-- SC2283 (error): Remove spaces around = to assign (or use [ ] to compare, or quote '=' if literal).
        ^-- SC1036 (error): '(' is invalid here. Did you forget to escape it?
        ^-- SC1088 (error): Parsing stopped here. Invalid use of parentheses?
  ```

Comment: What is not working? Just add a redirect to the file you want in each iteration.

Comment: Oh, you want `${array[@]}` not round parentheses. (But storing the arguments in an array which you use exactly once immediately after is just a waste of memory; simply call `search_elements "gomma" "lacca" "bromo"`.) Voting to close as typo.

Comment: ERROR: serandrew@serandrew-ThinkPad-T490:~/Documenti$ ./searchWords.sh
./searchWords.sh: riga 14: errore di sintassi vicino al token non atteso "("
./searchWords.sh: riga 14: `array = ("gomma" "lacca" "bromo")'

Comment: Oh yeah, another typo. Try https://shellcheck.net/ before asking for human assistance; and put the diagnostics in the question, not in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sigh. Here are the syntax errors fixed.

```
#!/bin/bash

# "function" keyword is unnecessary and ugly
search_elements(){
   # no need for an array
   for i; do
        # fix quoting and crazy indentation; add redirect
        pdfgrep -Hir "$i" . >"$i.txt"
   done
}

# remove spurious spaces
array=("gomma" "lacca" "bromo")

# braces, not parentheses
search_elements "${array[@]}"
```

Putting the logic in a function seems somewhat like over-engineering; this is simple enough to just live in a script which you call with the keywords you want to scan for.

```
#!/bin/sh
for i; do
    pdfgrep -Hir "$i" . >"$i.txt"
done
```

Nothing here uses Bash syntax; `/bin/sh` is more portable as well as faster on many platforms.

The shellcheck warnings are clickable links with more information about each error; please read what it tells you before you ask a human to help you.